# For and While loops in python

Tags: python

This is my first time trying for and while loops in python and i am getting stuck

here is my code...

```
print("Hello and welcome to the programme")

x = 0
y = 0
while (x < 100):
   print ('The count is: ', x + y)
   y = x + y
   x = x + 1

print ("The final answer is:", y)

print("Good Bye")

---------------------------------------

x = 0
y = 1

numberlist = (x + y)


for numbers in numberlist:
    print(int("count is "+ numbers))
```

The reason I included the while loop is because I want the for loop to work the exact same as the while loop and on the same programme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My best advice to you would be to go and do some python beginner tutorials. For instance, there's one on codeacademy.org and a couple on udacity.com for starters

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to your `while` loop using a `for` loop is:

```
y = 0
for x in range(0, 100):
    print ('The count is: ', x + y)
    y = x + y
```

If you just wanted the end result, you could use:

```
y = sum(range(0, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel this is a great help :)